# how to make global variable in python

Tags: python, global-variables, calculator

i want to make a calculator program such that on pressing each button the value of the button will  add to the string for example if 1 is pressed four times it should be 1111 so when i try do that it says variable referenced before assigned so that i may capture numbers of any digits but I'm having error: variable st referenced before assigned

```
st=""
def but1():
    v.set("1")
    global st=st+"1"
```

can we solve this error or is there any way to make the variable global?

```
def but1():

    st=st+"1"
    v.set(st)
def but2():
    st=st+"2"
    v.set(st)
def but3():
    st=st+"3"
    v.set(st)
def but4():
    st=st+"4"
    v.set(st)
def but5():
    st=st+"5"
    v.set(st)
def but6():
    st=st+"6"
    v.set(st)
def but7():
    st=st+"7"
    v.set(st)
def but8():
    st=st+"8"
    v.set(st)
def but9():
    st=st+"9"
    v.set(st)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` takes *just* the name that should be treated as a global:

```
def but1():
    global st
    v.set("1")
    st=st+"1"
```

You cannot put it on a line with a full expression.

The `global` declaration applies to the whole of the *current* scope (so to any use of the `st` name in the function). If you need to access `st` in multiple functions, you need to use the same keyword in *all* those functions.

Comment: but i want the same string to contain all the numbers clicked please check my entire code in answer

Comment: @MohdSanadZakiRizvi: then use `global` in **all** your functions.